# Python Script to Safely run Excel Macros

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a few excel process that are run in Macros. I have tried to automate the jobs and want to use python to:

1. Open excel
2. Add any com32 add-ins
3. Run the macro
4. When the macro is complete close the instance of excel

I have sample code below - I find that the code is sometimes unstable. It doesnt always add the add-in and I dont know when to close the excel object, i.e. if the macro runs for some time, the python script doesnt know to wait.

Are there better ways for achieving this? I would like to move more macros into python, but there are many users of the excel scripts so this is a longer term goal.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import traceback

DIRECTORY   = '*'
FILE        = '*.xlsm'
MACRO       = '*'   
path        = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, FILE)

if os.path.exists(path):
    try:
        xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlApp.RegisterXLL('*.xll')
        wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path)
        xlApp.Application.Run(MACRO)
        wb.Save()
        wb.Close()
        xlApp.Application.Quit()
        print('Code ran successfully.')
    except:
        print('An error was encountered; see traceback.')
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        xlApp.Quit()
```